# Is it possible for an optional argument value to depend on another argument in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, default-value, named-parameters

Does anyone know if something like this is possible in Scala:

```
case class Thing(property:String)

def f(thing:Thing, prop:String = thing.property) = println(prop)
```

The above code doesn't compile; giving the error `error: not found: value thing` at `thing.property`

The following shows the expected behaviour:

```
f(Thing("abc"), "123") // prints "123"
f(Thing("abc"))        // prints "abc"
```

I realise I could make the `prop` argument an `Option[String]` and do the check in the function definition, but I was wondering if there was a way around it with the new named/default argument support in 2.8.0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in Scala 2.8. Here's a quote from the ["Named and Default Arguments in Scala 2.8"](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/rytz/Mon,%202009-11-09,%2017:29/named-args.pdf) design document:

> Since the scope of a parameter extends
>   over all subsequent parameter lists
>   (and the method body), default
>   expressions can depend on parameters
>   of preceding parameter lists (but not
>   on other parameters in the same
>   parameter list). Note that when using
>   a default value which depends on
>   earlier parameters, the actual
>   arguments are used, not the default
>   arguments.

```
def f(a: Int = 0)(b: Int = a + 1) = b // OK
```

And another example:

```
def f[T](a: Int = 1)(b: T = a + 1)(c: T = b)
// generates:
// def f$default$1[T]: Int = 1
// def f$default$2[T](a: Int): Int = a + 1
// def f$default$3[T](a: Int)(b: T): T = b
```

According to this, your code may look as follows:

```
scala> case class Thing(property:String)
defined class Thing

scala> def f(thing:Thing)(prop:String = thing.property) = println(prop)
f: (thing: Thing)(prop: String)Unit

scala> f(Thing("abc"))("123")
123

scala> f(Thing("abc"))()
abc
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of thing I was after.

Comment: going to violate the DRY (don't repeat yourself): this is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution is just to overload the method:

```
case class Thing (property: String)

def f(thing: Thing, prop: String) = println(prop)

def f(thing: Thing) = f(thing, thing.property)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is how C++ defines optional / defaulted parameters, right?

Comment: It's a long time I programmed in C++, but you can ofcourse do the same thing in C++ or also in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `Option` is for. You can use the `getOrElse` method before the method call or inside the method `f`.

```
scala> val abc = Some("abc")
abc: Some[java.lang.String] = Some(abc)

scala> val none: Option[String] = None
none: Option[String] = None

scala> println(abc getOrElse "123")
abc

scala> println(none getOrElse "123")
123

scala> def f(o: Option[String]) = println(o getOrElse "123")
f: (o: Option[String])Unit

scala> f(abc)
abc

scala> f(none)
123
```

Oh here is something you could do via default arguments:

```
scala> case class Thing(property: String = "123")
defined class Thing

scala> def f(t: Thing) = println(t.property)
f: (t: Thing)Unit

scala> f(Thing("abc"))
abc

scala> f(Thing())
123
```

The expected behaviour can be achieved with simple overloading. I needed to put the method in an `object` because it looks like the REPL does not allow direct overloaded function declarations:

```
scala> object O {
         def overloaded(t:Thing) = println(t.property)
         def overloaded(t:Thing,s:String) = println(s)
       }
defined module O

scala> O.overloaded(Thing("abc"), "123")
123

scala> O.overloaded(Thing("abc"))
abc
```

Comment: But I think it is bad practice to be forced to provide `Option` instead of normal arguments.